# Executing jar file content using URL class loader

Tags: java, jar

I am in between writing an application which loads jar file dynamically and execute the class inside the jar file.
I am able to load the jar file and fetch the method as well,. but when i invoke the method, i doesn't execute the method, but there is no exception.

The method which i am trying to execute is public.

```
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader;
      //no paramater
        Class noparams[] = {};
        try {
            urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:///C:/Users/jamju02/Desktop/today/jar2.jar")});
             Class pluiginClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("plugintest.PluginTest");
            // Create a new instance from the loaded class
             Constructor<?> constructor = pluiginClass.getConstructor();

             Object classobject = constructor.newInstance();
             System.out.println(classobject.getClass().getName());
             //Method method = pluiginClass.getMethod("getName");
             Method[] m = pluiginClass.getDeclaredMethods();
                for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(m[i].toString());
                    m[i].setAccessible(true);
                    m[i].invoke(classobject, null);
                }

            // method.invoke(object);

              //call the printIt method
                Method method = pluiginClass.getDeclaredMethod("getName", noparams);
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(classobject);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


package plugintest;

public class PluginTest implements SimplePlugin {
 public String getName() {
        return "I'm the plugin!";
    }
}
```

It prints the class name and method name, but does not execute the method.

Comment: Can you post your `plugintest.PluginTest` code? How do you know that `getName()` is never executed? I assume it returns some `String` but you do not use the return value after the call.

Comment: @IKE: i have edited the post and added the plugin test class. The method getName returns a string value.

Comment: Is there any exception? I've modified the last line in try block to `System.err.println((String) method.invoke(classobject))` and the text is printed correctly.

Comment: No there is no exception.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeDFrX0J2eVhwTVk - your code is working here without any error

Comment: Thanks, it works, i was not printing the value after the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in try block needs to be changed to something like:

```
System.err.println((String) method.invoke(classobject));
```